# Sugar crm leads are not getting sync with pardot

Tags: sugarcrm, pardot

I am using Sugar crm and i am new to this . I am trying to sync my leads with pardot . But the problem is when i add a prospects in pardot it is automatically added to the CRM . But if i am adding a lead from Sugar crm it is not adding to pardot . I don't know how to check the errors behind this . 
 what i have done till now .

1) Added a connector (Sugar Crm) in my pardot account . Followed this [link](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2133064-sugarcrm-connector)

2) added pardot connector module in sugar crm by this [link](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2133073-sugarcrm-installer-package)

3) Connector setting in Pardot is

[image]

When i am adding a record from crm the field `pi_is_queued_c` in tabel `leads_cstm` is always 1 while for the records added from pardot is 0
please help me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can try:

1. Make sure you have version 24 or higher of Pardot's Sugar plugin
2. Check to see if any field updates you make in your CRM are syncing over to Pardot. If not, there might be a problem with the permissions in the CRM
3. If all that looks good, then try contacting Pardot support. It could be a bug within the connector.